# Material UI theme `overrides` not working while using `withStyles`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using `withStyles` HOC to provide classes to a component:

```
const styles = createStyles({
    Appbar: ({ backgroundColor }: BaseHeaderProps) => ({
      backgroundColor
    }),
    // ...moreStyles
});


export default withStyles(styles, { name: 'Component' })(Component);
```

I also need to be able to override the very same classes/styles in the global theme `overrides` object:

```
overrides: {
    Component: {
      Appbar: {
        backgroundColor: 'black',
      },
    },
   // more overrides...
```

The problem I am facing is that the styles in the `overrides` object will not apply/override the classes defined in the `createStyles`. The only way `overrides` would actually override is if the styles are "`prop-independent`", something like:

```
const styles = createStyles({
    Appbar: {
      backgroundColor: 'some-fixed-color',
    ),
    // ...moreStyles
});
```

Now, the `overrides` object will override this class and a `black` background color will be applied to the Appbar.

What I want is to be able to have this overridable functionality even when using "`prop-dependent`" styles, as the first one shows.

Maybe this helps: The "`prop-dependent`" callback that returns the style object NEVER gets called when `overrides` are used in the `Theme`. I have tried to log the `theme` object but it never is called.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, another component name for overload: "The MuiAppBar name can be used for providing default props or style overrides at the theme level"
https://v4.mui.com/api/app-bar/#appbar-api

```
export const CustomTheme = {
  overrides: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      backgroundColor: 'black', // ???
    },
    // more overrides..
  },
};
```